# Mercurial / hgweb : How to get latest revision description for each file on browse page?

Tags: mercurial, hgweb

I have local repo, and I need to view latest changes description per-file basis via web interface.

Look on examples (folder in Netbeans sources) :

1 - [on Netbeans native server](http://hg.netbeans.org/main-silver/file/1f5585db41b2/ant.kit)

2 - [on Bitbucket server](https://bitbucket.org/netbeans/main-silver/src/b8edc134468f48261104242278373bdf248ede16/ant.kit?at=default)

I have "1", but I want "2" (where we can see latest revision desc for each file). So, I try to modify hgweb templates (https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Theming) to reach this functionality, but in file list page template (manifest) variables to get rev desc not accessible. Only file name / size / permissions etc. available.

What can I do?

Comment: I'm under the impression that mercurial doesn't support log messages for each file, at least not in the way older version control systems like RCS do. Instead, mercurial logs a message for each changeset, which might include changes to any number of files. Maybe some markdown syntax in the log messages?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this by just modifying templates. You'd have to iterate over the files, looking at the linkrev for the filelog revision referred to by the manifest and get the changeset message from there.

Comment: I think about this already, but the main question is "how?" As far as I understand, I need to create my own scripts to iterate files (through various "hg ..." commands) and obtain needed data, but I have no time for this... :(

Comment: Maybe you can pay some someone to do that? Feel free to email me.